# Problems with @font-face on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css, font-face, helper

I downloaded an EOT font from the internet and it worked fine in IE, FF, and Chrome.  Then I downloaded a TTF font from dafont.com and I converted it to EOT and it did not work in Internet Explorer.

Can someone tell me the reason, or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what went wrong but using [this generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) always produces a result that works in IE.

Comment: lol, it worked :P i rly don't understand it...  thx anyway ;)